# Passing a macro to function expecting optional star

Tags: conditionals, xparse

Initially this was meant as conditional typesetting using `xparse` rather than the other packages proposed [here](http://Conditional%20typesetting%20/%20build). Perhaps there are better approaches than the one I am pursuing, for that purpose, but in any case the question should be relevant wrt `xparse`. Under "In other words" should read
"If you are reading from a mobile device, paper size should look appropriate.".

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Uncomment either of the two <---------
\NewDocumentCommand{\ismobile}{}{*}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\ismobile}{}{}
% ------------------------------------->
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifMobile}{smm}
{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {#2}
  {#3}  
}\NewDocumentCommand{\ifmobile}{mm}
{
  \ifMobile\ismobile{#1}{#2}
}

\ifmobile
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A6}
  \KOMAoption{DIV}{20}
}
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A4}
}

\begin{document}

 If you are reading from a%TODO suppress gap here
 \ifMobile*{mobile device}{PC}%TODO suppress gap here
 , paper size should be \ifMobile*{A6}{A4}. 

And:

 If you are reading from a%TODO suppress gap here
 \ifMobile{mobile device}{PC}%TODO suppress gap here
 , paper size should be \ifMobile{A6}{A4}. 

In otherwords:

 If you are reading from a
 \ifmobile{mobile device}{PC}%BUG
 , paper size should look appropriate.

%\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Shot]

Comment: The `\ifMobile` macro inside `\ifmobile` only sees `\ismobile`, which is not (yet) a `*`.

Comment: `\ismobile` is not `*`, it *expands* to `*`. You want the wine, not the (corked) bottle of wine.

Comment: Ha ha, is an expand after issue?

Comment: also note you need `%` in all the lines of your definitions otherwise your macros add spurious spaces in the output  like `A4 .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As egreg said, your version doesn't work because `xparse` looks for an *explicit* `*`. Here's a version using an `expl3` boolean variable:

I defined a boolean variable `\g__erwann_mobile_bool` which should be true in the mobile version and false otherwise. The commands `\MobileVersion` and `\PrintVersion` switch that boolean accordingly.

The command `\ifmobileTF` checks for that boolean and selects the correct version (I changed the name because it took me a while to realise you had `\ifMobile` and `\ifmobile` :-).

The command `\ifMobile` picks the first argument if the optional star is given and the second argument otherwise. I must say I don't see much purpose in this command, though...

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g__erwann_mobile_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \MobileVersion { }
  { \bool_gset_true:N \g__erwann_mobile_bool }
\NewDocumentCommand \PrintVersion { }
  { \bool_gset_false:N \g__erwann_mobile_bool }
\NewDocumentCommand \ifmobileTF { +m +m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \g__erwann_mobile_bool
      {#1} {#2}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \ifMobile { s +m +m }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      {#2} {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% Allow these only in the preamble
\makeatletter
\@onlypreamble \MobileVersion
\@onlypreamble \PrintVersion
\makeatother

% Set appropriate version
\MobileVersion
% \PrintVersion

\ifmobileTF
  {
    \KOMAoption{paper}{A6}
    \KOMAoption{DIV}{20}
  }
  {
    \KOMAoption{paper}{A4}
  }

\begin{document}

 If you are reading from a
 \ifMobile*{mobile device}{PC},
 paper size should be \ifMobile*{A6}{A4}.

And:

 If you are reading from a
 \ifMobile{mobile device}{PC},
 paper size should be \ifMobile{A6}{A4}.

In otherwords:

 If you are reading from a
 \ifmobileTF{mobile device}{PC},
 paper size should look appropriate.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought `ExplSyntax-On`/`-Off` was a superset of `makeat-letter`/`-other`. Apparently not...

Comment: @Erwann (Sorry, I forgot to reply your comment) `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`Off` is more or less like `\makeatletter`/`other`, yes. `\makeatletter` makes the `@` character a letter (so that it can be used in `\m@cro@names`). `\ExplSyntaxOn` makes `_` and `:` letters (so that they can be used in `\macro_names:`). `\ExplSyntaxOn` also makes spaces and line ends be ignored and a few other changes, while `\makeatletter` changes only the `@`. `\ExplSyntaxOn` doesn't change the `@` though.

Answer (score 2):

Using `xparse` doesn't free you from protecting end-of-lines.

Your problem is that `\ismobile` is not `*`, but something that eventually prints a `*`. On the other hand, a command with an `s` argument tests for the presence of an explicit `*`.

You *could* do like

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Uncomment either of the two <---------
%\newcommand{\ismobile}{*}
\newcommand{\ismobile}{}

% ------------------------------------->
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifMobile}{smm}
{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifmobile}{mm}
{%
  \expandafter\ifMobile\ismobile{#1}{#2}%
}

\ifmobile
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A6}
  \KOMAoption{DIV}{20}
}
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A4}
}

\begin{document}

If you are reading from a \ifmobile{mobile device}{PC},
paper size should look appropriate.

\end{document}
```

Easier:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{mobile}
\toggletrue{mobile}
\newcommand{\ifmobile}[2]{\iftoggle{mobile}{#1}{#2}}

\ifmobile
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A6}
  \KOMAoption{DIV}{20}
}
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A4}
}

\begin{document}

If you are reading from a \ifmobile{mobile device}{PC},
paper size should look appropriate.

\end{document}
```

Comment out the `\toggletrue` line for A4 paper.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with through trial and error (needed to be reacquainted with `expl3`) so I suspect `\exp_last_two_unbraced:Noo` not the most straightFW.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

%% Uncomment either of the two <---------
%\NewDocumentCommand{\ismobile}{}{*}
%%\NewDocumentCommand{\ismobile}{}{}
%% ------------------------------------->

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifMobile}{smm}
{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {#2}
  {#3}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn   
\tl_set:Nn \l_ismobile_tl {*}
% \tl_set:Nn \l_ismobile_tl {}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn   %Why outer?
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifmobile}{mm}
{
%   \exp_after:wN \ifMobile \exp_after:wN % Nope
%   \exp_args:NNo \ifMobile % Nope
%  \l_ismobile_tl
%  {#1}{#2}
  \exp_last_two_unbraced:Noo\ifMobile
  {\l_ismobile_tl}{{#1}{#2}}
}
  \ExplSyntaxOff

\ifmobile
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A6}
  \KOMAoption{DIV}{20}
}
{
  \KOMAoption{paper}{A4}
}

\begin{document}

 If you are reading from a%TODO suppress gap here
 \ifMobile*{mobile device}{PC}%TODO suppress gap here
 , paper size should be \ifMobile*{A6}{A4}. 

And:

 If you are reading from a%TODO suppress gap here
 \ifMobile{mobile device}{PC}%TODO suppress gap here
 , paper size should be \ifMobile{A6}{A4}. 

In otherwords:

 If you are reading from a
 \ifmobile{mobile device}{PC}%BUG
 , paper size should look appropriate.

%\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: A6]

[image: A4]

Comment: `\exp_last_two_unbraced:Noo\ifMobile{\l_ismobile_tl}{{#1}{#2}}` is the same as `\exp_last_unbraced:No\ifMobile{\l_ismobile_tl}{#1}{#2}` and `\exp_after:wN\ifMobile\l_ismobile_tl{#1}{#2}`, and `\expandafter\ifMobile\l_ismobile_tl{#1}{#2}`